# GDPR warning Keeps Reappearing on Admob console

Tags: java, android, kotlin, admob, gdprconsentform

I have thoroughly implemented the mandatory General Data Protection Regulation (Gdpr) consent form on all my apps -- both Android and Ios platforms -- however, for two months now, the error has been continually reappearing and then suddenly disappearing. Below I have provided the code of how I have attempted to instigate the Gdpr consent. Could it be that I am doing something incorrectly? Is there an underlying issue that I am not seeing? I would be incredibly grateful if someone could help me solve this challenging problem I am facing.

```
public void ObtainGDPRConsent(){
        // Set tag for under age of consent. false means users are not under
        // age.

        // Use this if the user or the app is 18+
        ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters
                .Builder()
                .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
                .build();
        consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this);
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
                this,
                params,
                new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdateSuccess() {
                        // The consent information state was updated.
                        // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
                        if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED){
                            if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable()) {
                                loadForm();
                            }
                            Log.e("Obtain GDPR Consent", "Consent required, load form "+consentInformation.getConsentStatus());
                        }else{
                            if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() != ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.UNKNOWN){
                                InnitializeAdmobSdk();
                                Load_Admob_ads();
                                Log.e("Obtain GDPR Consent", "Consent not required & unknown "+consentInformation.getConsentStatus());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError formError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                        if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() != ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED &&
                                consentInformation.getConsentStatus() != ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.UNKNOWN){
                            InnitializeAdmobSdk();
                            Load_Admob_ads();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    public void loadForm() {
        // Loads a consent form. Must be called on the main thread.
        UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
                this,
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadSuccessListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadSuccess(ConsentForm consentForm) {
                        MainActivity.this.consentForm = consentForm;
                        if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                            consentForm.show(
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    new ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onConsentFormDismissed(@Nullable FormError formError) {
                                            if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.OBTAINED) {
                                                // App can start requesting ads.
                                                InnitializeAdmobSdk();
                                                Load_Admob_ads();
                                            }

                                            // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                                            loadForm();
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                },
                new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoadFailure(FormError formError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                        Log.e("Obtain GDPR Consent", "Consent form failed to load "+consentInformation.getConsentStatus());
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```